# Program to restore open windows after crash

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, restore

Are there any programs (for PC) that will constantly monitor what programs and windows within those programs you have open, and then restore each of those windows in case of a crash/forced restart? (looking specifically for Outlook, but open to all ideas)?

Something similar to Chrome's feature where after a crash, it says "Looks like Chrome didn't shut down properly. Would you like to restore your open tabs?"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

RollBack Rx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback_Rx

Comment: RollBack Rx only takes a snap shot of data stored on the harddrive, as stated by http://rollbacksoftware.com/ (which by the way is the correct link to the software). Since windows doesn't store which programs have been opened this software doesn't help at all with providing an solution/answer to the question. Also it has no "real time" update of the snapshot, so it would not show the most recent system state (unless the snap shot - by any chance - has been taken right before the restart)